# I can't Draw on a canvas it keeps me back my main screen

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, ondraw

hi i'm new at android and i want to create an image that will move across the screen but everytime i create a costume view and draw on it the application keeps on bringing me back to my main screen.

here is my main screen named MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.prototype2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageButton start;
ImageView quit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
    quit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quit_btn);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Map.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

this is my map class that will be directed to the game named Map.calss

```
package com.example.prototype2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Map extends Activity{

Button game1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    game1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_game1);

    game1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, patintero.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });



    }

    }
```

and this will be the class were i want to draw the moving object named patintero.java

```
package com.example.prototype2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class patintero extends Activity{

DrawDefender v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = new DrawDefender(this);
    setContentView(v);


}

}
```

and lastly my costume view named DrawDefender.java

```
 package com.example.prototype2;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;

 public class DrawDefender extends View{

Bitmap defender1;
int x, y;


public DrawDefender(Context context) {
    super(context);
    defender1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walk1);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    if (y < canvas.getHeight()){
        y += 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; y == 0; i++) {
        y -= 10;
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(defender1, x, y, new Paint());

}

 }
```

i badly need some help.. is there something wrong that i did? i a beginner in android please help me :)

Comment: can you add your layout/map.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in its current state your image just sits at the top center of the screen doing nothing?

That's because you're putting it there, every time your view gets drawn.

The onDraw Methods gets called by your view every time it needs to update itself, which is the case after you call `invalidate();` on your view.

To use this, make a handler (android.os.handler, not the java one) in your view and let it invalidate the view after it's drawn:

```
import android.os.handler  //should be imported autoamtically, jsut make sure it doesnt say java.something...

Handler animHandler;    //  <- declare handler out of contructor so you can use it anywhere

public DrawDefender(Context context){
    super(context);
    defender1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walk1);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    animHandler = new Handler();
}

//For making the handler invalidate your view, see usage below
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    run(){
        invalidate();
    }
};

onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    //Dont need super.onDraw(canvas), as it doesn't do anything.
    //still do you other stuff, 
    //although that for loop gets completed before your view ever gets drawn, 
    //which is why your image always is at x=canvas.getWidth()/2 and y=0
    //maybe do a java tutorial first to get into programming generally before specifically doing android, 
    //not sure how much experience you have here

    animHandler.post(r); 
          //or .postDelayed(r, 30); to make framerate 30fps
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry forgot to change the for loop condition, but still it does not work...i have followed some tutorial and copied it exactly but still the result is the same, every time i click the button to bring me to the animation the application brings me back to the main screen.

Comment: Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    run(){
        invalidate();
    }
};

gives error used

Runnable r = new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
         invalidate();
     }

 };

instead, is it right?

Comment: Right sorry, should have mentioned, your IDE is always righter than me ;) 
Is there an error message in the logcat the moment the new activity opens/closes?

Comment: i found one but when i try it again their are no the same error message..what king of error should i watch for?

Comment: Do log level "error" and filter: only selected application (i suppose you use android studio, but should be similar with other IDEs). Then the logcat should give you just a few messages, maybe even including a stacktrace from an exception.